# CSS: arrow-icon should stick to bottom when text breaks into multiple lines

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me how i do this:
Basically i have a box with border and text inside and an arrow on the right center. And  the arrow button should stick to the bottom as seen in the second screenshot if the text is more than one line.

[Arrow without line break]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2EG7.png

[Arrow with two or more lines]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv1MW.png

Comment: Please provide some of your code. Is this a after content or img or what is the arrow?. If you provide code this will be taken care of pretty quick here.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example